# Regex / preg_match to find 13 character unique ID

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My database creates new entries using the PHP uniqid function. This means the ID is 13 characters and a mix of numbers and letters.

Examples of IDs:

- 5a0ae6fa29476
- 5a26822fbfd19
- 5a2a952fc9558

When an email comes in, it is meant to check the subject for a # followed by the ID - example subject: "Re: [Item #5a0ae6fa29476] Need Info". It must contain the #.

I'd like to use preg_match / regex to pull the ID from the email.

I'm currently using:

```
/(?!#)\w{13}/
```

But the problem with it is that the # is not important and the following strings in email subjects will still be processed:

- 5a0ae6fa29476
- 13_characters
- Communications
- (any 13 character string involving letters, numbers or underswcores)

Can anyone advise a better regex to use? Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using a negative lookahead which is always true in this case. It seems you want to match `#`, try `/#\w{13}/` or even `/#\w{13}\b/`

Comment: Thank you very much. Just what I needed! It still pulls the # but I can remove that afterwards without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *match* the `#` symbol before the 13 digits, but you may also discard it easily with the `\K` operator:

```
/#\K\w{13}\b/
```

**Details**

- `#` - a `#` symbol
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `\w{13}` -  13 word chars ending with a
- `\b` - word boundary

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZJNWeg/1).

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: Done. Thank you :)